# How to convert results of a group by into a json using POSTGRESQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate

I have the following question:
If I have this data in a table:

[image]

How could you get a result like this:

[image]

It would be the same for me if the result came in a json like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get the aggregated JSON you can use `jsonb_object_agg()`

```
select users, jsonb_object_agg(day, polls)
from data
group by users;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f2c7321ed49f88ad7bec5a65f217dc06)